# What is the difference between TextView and TextViewCompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I need to know what actual difference between TextView and [TextViewCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/TextViewCompat.html).
When we should use [TextViewCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/TextViewCompat.html)?

Comment: TextViewCompat comes from the compatibility libary. Its main role is to backport new features up to android API level 4. Therefore if you don't need such new features, stay with regular TextView.

Answer (score 19):

In much the same way as other compatibility classes, it exists to provide backwards compatibility for new functions to older versions of Android.

If you compare the two, you will see the difference.

One such example is [getMaxLines()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getMaxLines()). In an ordinary `TextView`, this requires SDK level 16. `TextViewCompat` introduces such functions for SDK levels from 4.

Answer (score 1):

define TextViewCompat  in developer.android

A TextView which supports compatible features on older version of the platform, including:

Supports **textAllCaps** style attribute which works back to **Gingerbread**.
    Allows dynamic tint of it background via the background tint methods in ViewCompat.
    Allows setting of the background tint using **backgroundTint** and **backgroundTintMode**.